# Ubuntu 18 keeps on restarting automatically (triggered by moving the laptop)

Tags: boot, power-management, laptop, battery, restart

I have a ubuntu 18.04 system on an [Asus ZenBook](https://www.asus.com/in/Laptops/ASUS-ZenBook-UX305UA/) laptop. I am facing the issue that my laptop keeps on restarting again and again. It started an hour ago. I have tried shutting down once but problem is still there after shutting down and booting the system.

It doesn't seem a battery problem as I got my battery changed a month ago so it'll be good to presume that battery is doing fine. Right now I am actually working in recovery mode and (till now) doesn't seem that the problem occurs (repeated automatic restarting) in recovery mode.

Also a maybe related issue could be that few days ago I left my system on overnight and it got turned off due to zero battery. Since then everytime I restart/boot my system it shows wrong time (the time battery drained or sometime before that even (probably last reboot before that battery drainage))

Also [this screen](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1o-G9BLx1TdB3J6zTHImuzurrkFKyY87g/view?usp=sharing) comes up when the system reboots.

How to resolve this issue??

**EDIT1**

As asked in the question output of var/log/syslog

```
Sep 16 19:05:31 ZenBook systemd-timesyncd[577]: Timed out waiting for reply from 91.189.94.4:123 (ntp.ubuntu.com).
```

Sep 16 is also the time it shows after system boots up..!!

**EDIT 2**

Anotger weird thing i observed is that this unwelcome restart occurs when i move the laptop (even lift it slightly) . (though it still doesn't occur in recovery mode so believe not exactly hardware ussue)

**EDIT 3**

Same thing is happenening when i boot from a live usb. So this probably means system/hardware fault right? Also on a live cd the fan is blowing even during grub or so!

Comment: I find the phrase "I have tried shutting down once nothing happened." what do you mean? were you able to shut down? what do you mean nothing happened?

Comment: Oh no I meant that if it was a fling and shutting down system cured the problem but it did not. I'll clarify it once!

Comment: Clarified in problem statement

Comment: How often between unwelcome restarts? Does the behavior occur if you boot from a LiveUSB? What is in your /var/log/syslog at the time of a restart?

Comment: It has been varying, sometimes takes few minutes upto 10 max maybe sometimes even before I type password on screen. Haven't check liveCd, will try. How to check /var/log/syslog during restart??

Comment: You note the exact time of a restart, and look for those timestamps in the log later.

Comment: Hi @user535733 in var/log/syslog it has time 19:04/19:05 Sep 16 (which is the time on my system when the system starts), updating the question also

Comment: Since there is no logging of a software problem (cannot reach an NTP server won't cause a reboot), the problem does not seem to be Ubuntu-related. Start looking at hardware: The two most common are overheating and faulty power supply.

Comment: @user535733 I get what you mean, can you think of some reason that would explain what it works in recovery mode??

Comment: I can think of several, but that does not seem relevant. All your symptoms point to hardware fault of some kind.

Comment: Oh sure, I am going to give it for repair anyways! Thanks a lot!