# Do the same set of graphics drivers work across ubuntu versions?

Tags: boot, drivers, laptop, restart

I have an Asus Laptop which had ubuntu 18 installed on it. On fine day my laptop started restarting automatically on moving it even slightly. ([details!](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1077317/ubuntu-18-keeps-on-restarting-automatically-triggered-by-moving-the-laptop)).

Now the same thing happens with ubuntu 16 or a bootable pen drive of ubuntu 18. 
But surprisingly on using ubuntu 14 my laptop works fine, (as well as it works fine with windows). I had given the device to repair (considering it was hardware issue). But given it works with windows they are saying it's not hardware issue and probably issue with linux drivers (which does makes sense).

So I wanted to know does it make sense for it to work with ubuntu 14 but not wubuntu 18. Do they not use same/similar deivers???

Also I never explicitly downloaded and driver when workig with ubuntu. I don't know how to reinstall correct drivers. If someone could tell any procedure it would be great.

Comment: Just for your information, there is no release of Ubuntu called "Ubuntu 18", there is only 18.04 and 18.10. Similarly, there is no "Ubuntu 16", there is only 16.04 and 16.10. Ubuntu releases twice a year. The first number in the version number refers to the year (18 means 2018), and the second number refers to the month.

Comment: Yeah I know, I just wrote that for short!!!

Answer (score 0):

What graphics hardware do you have? And why do you suspect it's the graphics drivers? It does sounds like you're experiencing ACPI issues. Your previous post doesn't reveal much other than you probably have a ZenBook, and your machine couldn't sync your laptop's time with an NTP server. It's possible that the newer kernel in 18.04 is doing something that's making your ZenBook run hot, hence the reason why it restarts when moved/lifted/bumped.

Just a wild guess, but you could try adding the following kernel parameters:

```
i915.enable_execlists=0
```

and

```
acpi_osi=! acpi_osi='Windows 2009'
```

To add kernel parameters you need to edit `/etc/default/grub` (as root) using your favorite editor. You then add, inside the quotes, the lines above to the line starting with `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT`. So your `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT` might look something like this:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash i915.enable_execlists=0 acpi_osi=! acpi_osi='Windows 2009'"
```

Once you have modified your kernel parameters in `/etc/default/grub`, run the following:

```
$ sudo update-grub
```

After that, reboot, and see if it solves the issue.

if `acpi_osi='Windows 2009'` doesn't work, try `acpi_osi='Windows 2015'`.

If you're unable to boot in to a stable Ubuntu 18.04 to add the above kernel parameters, you may have to first temporarily add them during the boot process. Details on how to do this can be found here:

[How do I add a kernel boot parameter?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/19486/how-do-i-add-a-kernel-boot-parameter)

Comment: 1) I have Intel integrated Graphics. 2) I gave my laptop for repair, they said it's likely a driver issue. I don't have much understanding of how exactly things work under the hood but it made sense.

Comment: Did you try what I have written above?

Comment: Also I had been using Ubuntu 18 for 2 months, how can suddenly it start going wrong suddenly?

Comment: My laptop will arrive back by tomorrow, will be able to try it only then, Thanks for response!

Comment: I see. The direct answer to your question is "No - the same graphics drivers are not necessarily used from one version of a distro to the next". A lot of the drivers are "built in" to the Linux kernel. Newer kernels have newer features that are not always backwards compatible. This is why people with brand new hardware often install the latest bleeding edge Linux kernels (even release candidates of the kernel!). This is what I had to do to get a Ryzen desktop rig working.

Comment: HINT: In future - provide more information (at leave give the make and model of your laptop, along with what hardware it has). By doing so, you increase the chances of someone else who has the same hardware answering your question.